# How to modify CSS of a <select> dropdown?

Tags: html, css, select

I was wondering if there is any method to modify the style of the dropdown lists of a `<select>` tag?

Given the code (for example)

```
<select>
 <option>CSS</option>
 <option>HTML </option>
 <option>HTML 5</option>
</select>
```

Any css for `<select>` would only modify the box itself, but not the dropdown... The background color can be changed but beyond that, is it possible to perform a heavy customization? [htmllion.com](http://www.htmllion.com/test.html?fileroot=css&filename=select-dropdown)

I'd like to achieve bootstrap alike dropdown lists. [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_comp_dropdown-menu&stacked=h)

With shadows and a custom style.
Is that possible?

Comment: I've found this: https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/ :/ so it is completely impossible?

Comment: Try to refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript. I hope it will help.

Comment: CHeck out this **[link](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/pvfyt)**

Comment: Probably the best and more battle tested solution around is [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to style the dropdown list of a html select. But you can build your own dropdown list or use a framework like bootstrap.